# Distributional derivative of $\log(|x|)$ in higher dimensions

Tags: real-analysis, partial-differential-equations, distribution-theory

I was attempting to compute the distributional Laplacian of the function $|x|^{2-n}$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$ for $n \geq 3$.

I have reduced it down to showing that, setting $r = |x|$, the identity $$\partial_r \log r = C(n)r^{n-1}\delta$$
holds in the distributional sense, where $C(n)$ is some dimensional constant and $\delta$ is the Dirac delta at the origin.

I was unable to find this computation anywhere before for this higher dimensional case. The one dimensional case is almost tautologically the principal value distribution of $1/x$, which is certainly not a Dirac delta. Therefore, I'd at least like some idea of why it would become a Dirac delta in higher dimensions, if not a full computation.

Comment: If it matters, the dimensional constant $C(n)$ is $\omega_{n-1}/(n-1)$, where $\omega_{n-1}$ is the volume of the $(n-1)$-dimensional Euclidean unit ball.

Comment: I don't understand, $r$ is a radius (hence 1D) and $\partial_r \log r = 1/r \neq C(n) \delta$ regardless of the space that $x$ lives in, right?

Comment: Whoops! It should really be something like $C(n)r^{n-1}\delta$. This is what I get for working backwards. The original claim is that $\Delta r^{2-n} = (n-2)\omega_{n-1}\delta$. We can compute the left-hand side to be $(n-1)(n-2)r^{1-n}\partial_r(\log r)$, which yields my proposed expression. I'd agree that something seems fishy here...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> > **Proposition:** If $n\geq 3$, then $\Delta\left(|x|^{2-n}\right)=C_n\delta$ on $\mathbb{R}^n$, where $C_n=-(n-2)A(S^{n-1}).$

I'll give a sketched proof, and I can fill in details tomorrow morning, if need be.

Proof: Let $u\in C_0^\infty(\mathbb{R}^n)$, and set $\Omega_\epsilon=\mathbb{R}^n\setminus B_\epsilon(0).$ Then, \begin{align*}\langle \Delta u,|x|^{2-n}\rangle &=\lim_{\epsilon\rightarrow 0}\int\limits_{\Omega_\epsilon}\Delta u\cdot |x|^{2-n} dx\\
&=\lim_{\epsilon\rightarrow 0}\int\limits_{\Omega_\epsilon}(\Delta u|x|^{2-n}-u\Delta |x|^{2-n})dx,\end{align*} using that $\Delta|x|^{2-n}=0$ for $x\neq 0.$ Applying Green's formula, we get that the above equals $$-\lim_{\epsilon\rightarrow 0}\int\limits_{\partial B_\epsilon(0)}(\epsilon ^{2-n}\partial_r u-(2-n)\epsilon^{1-n})dS.$$ Since $A(\partial B_\epsilon(0))=\epsilon^{n-1} A(S^{n-1}),$ the above limit is $-(n-2)u(0) A(S^{n-1})$, as desired.

Comment: Thanks, this makes sense (modulo the application of Green's formula which I think is easily verified).

Comment: I was using this version of Green's formula (Green's second identity): $\int\limits_{\Omega} (v\Delta u-u\Delta v)dx=\int\limits_{\partial\Omega} \left(u\frac{\partial u}{\partial\nu}-u\frac{\partial v}{\partial\nu}\right) dS.$

Answer (score 0):

There is a correct proof already, so some remarks on your attempt.

- the correct formula cannot be $r^{n-1}\delta$ as this can only be interpreted as the zero distribution. Also multiplying by the nonsmooth function $r^{n-1}$ is a little suspect.
- The correct laplacian formula for smooth radial functions is
  $$ \Delta f=\frac{1}{r^{n-1}} \frac{d}{d r}\left(r^{n-1} f'\right) $$
  and you have $f=r^{2-n}$. Correctly computing this should give you $f'=r^{1-n}$ and therefore $\Delta f = 0$. The reason this doesn't give you the $\delta$ is because this formula only holds away from the singularity $x=0$. For test functions whose support contain 0, you should perform the careful limitting procedure in the other answer.